# Regex to find specified Value

Tags: regex

I need a regex to get only the month of value between string and year, and one regex to find only the year. Any number of spaces can exist.

What I tried:

```
(?<=MyString)([\s]*)((?:Jan(?:uar)?|Feb(?:ruar)?|Mär(?:z)?|Apr(?:il)?|Mai?|Jun(?:i)?|Jul(?:i)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Okt(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dez(?:ember)?)) ((?:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3})(?=\D|$))
```

I cannot figure out how to ignore the spaces. How can I get this result?

Sample:

```
MyString     Januar        2019
Regex 1: Januar
Regex 2: 2016
```

Comment: Can you post some sample texts and expected output?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have edit for a sample.

Comment: Please also indicate which language and/or regex flavor you are using. See further the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info).

Comment: The problem is I don't know what regex language so I try different variantes: https://www.ecodms.de/index.php/en/faq/knowledge-base/159-faq-entries-ecodms-archive/ecodms-client/973-tipps-tricks-zur-verwendung-von-regular-expressions-regex-im-vorlagen-designer-von-ecodms (The regex in bottom)

Comment: You are already capturing the groups, you just need to consult your language's documentation to figure out how to get the captured groups. Your regex is fine; so this is really a language question, not a regex question - but we don't know which language you are using.

Comment: So your programming language is PHP then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex just needs a whitespace construct `\s*` between the month and year  :

```
(?<=MyString)(\s*)((?:Jan(?:uar)?|Feb(?:ruar)?|Mär(?:z)?|Apr(?:il)?|Mai?|Jun(?:i)?|Jul(?:i)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Okt(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dez(?:ember)?))\s*((?:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3})(?=\D|$))
```

Note that there should be no need to capture the whitespace `(\s*)`
at the beginning unless it is being used as a flag in a code sense.

Comment: Thank you. But for the software (See link) I need a regex where I get only the monath and a second for only the year (additional if it possible the month in number?)

Comment: What link ? What is being said, I'm not familiar with any of it. Maybe it is C++ and not regex that the question is about.

Comment: here are samples from company: https://www.ecodms.de/index.php/en/faq/knowledge-base/159-faq-entries-ecodms-archive/ecodms-client/973-tipps-tricks-zur-verwendung-von-regular-expressions-regex-im-vorlagen-designer-von-ecodms But I don't understand what language this is

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't speak German. If any of those authors need professional regex advice, have them contact me personally.

Comment: No problem. Thank you. I hope it givs a change for "MyString Januar 2019) to get only moth without group needed

Comment: See, that's the thing. Seperately, use 2 regex `Jan(?:uar)?|Feb(?:ruar)?|Mär(?:z)?|Apr(?:il)?|Mai?|Jun(?:i)?|Jul(?:i)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Okt(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dez(?:ember)?` and `(?:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3})(?=\D|$)` Or, combine them and grab the groups. Here is what you **can't** do : Can't use a variable width _Negative Look Behind_  to validate that it is either a month or a year. The only engine that supports variable width lookbehind assertions is the Dot-Net engine. These are the options available to use. Cannot do it any other ways, other than as mentioned in this comment.

Comment: Great. Thank you